# Cakephp routing: using dash had broke it

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have the following 2 routes.

```
Router::connect('/photo-gallery/:slug-:id', 
                    array('controller' => 'company_categories', 'action' => 'photo_gallery'),
                    array(
                        'pass' => array('id'),
                        'id' => "[0-9]+"
                    )
    );


Router::connect('/:slug-my-string-:id',
                    array('controller' => 'company_categories', 'action' => 'category_companies'),
                    array(
                        'id' => "[0-9]+",
                        'pass' => array('id')
                    )
    );
```

While the first works, the second doesn't.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: What url are you using to access each?

Comment: An explample of url for the one that is not working would be "/Company-category-my-string-9/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I finally found and it works as expected is the following:

```
Router::connect('/:slug-:string-:id',
                    array('controller' => 'company_categories', 'action' => 'category_companies'),
                    array(
                        'id' => "[0-9]+",
                        'string' => "my-string"
                        'pass' => array('id')
                    )
    );
```

This way I can handle all kind of static strings used in route url pattern and there is no problem anymore regarding the parsing of dashes ("-"), which I think it was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your second route doesn't work because the whole string ":slug-my-string" is parsed as a route element not just ":slug" as you expect. [Reference](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Route/CakeRoute.php#L135).